# Creating Vanity URLs

Tags: php, url, architecture

I currently run a site where I want to give people the ability to make their own URLs.  For example, here is my URL:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/hiker_community/hiker_public_profile.php?community_member_id=2

You see, it is named just by id, which is uninteresting and also bad for SEO (not that it matters here).

Ideally I want my site members to also have their names in the URL.  How is that typically done?  So in my case, it would be something like:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/alex-genadinik and have the id hidden.

Is that possible?  Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need router, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework

Comment: I think in that thread, they over-complicate things.  What if you could just put the vanity URL into the database as one of the fields for that entity.  You will be fetching things from the db anyway, so might as well fetch the vanity URL and redirect there.  What do you think?

Comment: there a many ways to skin a cat - fetching things from DB and return vanity URL it is basic router, frameworks got complex one, you just need to know how they work and use full or just partial to get job done - your job

Answer (score 2):

[Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) is a great MVC framework which provides configuration derived routes, which can easily be configured to send all requests through a common controller, where content can be dynamically pulled from a database and rendered.

Here is an example of a basic routing rule, which excludes request for users, students, and lessons, but routes all other request to a common content controller.

So if you request *http://mydomain.com/hiking-and-camping-info*, the url would be parsed, and *hiking-and-camping-info* would be looked up in the database and the related content pulled down.

Routing configuration:

```
$route['^(?!lessons|students|users|content).*'] = 'content';
```

and the content controller then grabs the url segment and finds the matching content and loads it:

```
class Content extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->model('Content_model', 'content');
    }

    function index() {
        $content_url = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $data['content'] = $this->content->get_content_by_name($content_url);
        $this->load->view('content', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is accomplished via the use of an htaccess file on a server with mod_rewrite (most Linux servers).  An example might be like:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^/(alex[\-]genadinik)$ /hiker_community/hiker_public_profile.php?       community_member_name=$1
```

This implies that your hiker_public_profile.php script will need to accept "alex-genadinik" as $_GET variable "community_member_name," and then query the database via the name instead of the ID.

So you'd take the above code, save it in a file called ".htaccess," and then upload it to the root directory of your website.  Learning regular expressions is recommended.

Comment: One big disadvantage - need to have rules for all 'hikers'

Comment: While that is a valid point, it isn't necessarily true.  You could point all strings to "parser.php" or something and then have parser.php check to see if the given string corresponds to a hiker's name and output the hiker page.  If it doesn't correspond to a hiker's name, maybe look for that name + .php and load it.  However, that would be slow.  Personally, I would change the page to: http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/users/alex-genadinik and then match any string after /users/ to the page to load a hiker profile.  Then you would only need one rule.

Comment: it is very true - this solution is called router

Comment: The first option I gave is called router.  The second option (the one I recommended) is not.

Comment: I think @bensiu got it right.  It seems like there is lots of hard-coding that has to be done if each new member and item for which there is its own URL.